Gitlab LFS fsck nonCanonicalPointer: Pointer for [...] was not canonical
I have a repo with LFS enabled, and I just wanted to push a new commit. However, when trying to push I get the error:
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".
After researching various approaches, I noticed that git lfs fsck returns a number of:
pointer: nonCanonicalPointer: Pointer for eee8c92cedc6b826bf89e2f8503b6ba6da2a99c8e22debc024871b58c7429f0d (blob 0ab1d7bf38d1f31eea14132a17ba7f47bfb31a7b) was not canonical
I can't find anything online that corresponds to this issue, any tips on how to resolve this would be much appreciated!
I've tried various solutions given here, sadly to no effect: Git error: Encountered 7 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't
